# spring data mongo Language annotation

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

i'm trying to figure out how to use the @Language annotation from spring-data-rest-mongo project; 
I would like to store and retrive mongo document and do query on them; the simple document is as follow:

> {
>   id: "abc",
>       name: "light",
>       "description": "wave or particle"
>       }

I would like to store it and retrive it with different languages; 
any hint about it?

some sample using spring-data-rest would be greatly appreciated

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Language` annotation is used to set the [language_override](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#use-any-field-to-specify-the-language-for-a-document) property for a full text index and therefore does not help designing a collection of mulitlingual documents.
For more information please see the [MongoDB Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and the Spring Data MongoDB [Full Text Search support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.full-text).

Answer (score 0):

To perform a search for a certain language I usually follow this approach: [Multi-language documents example](https://github.com/ciri-cuervo/spring-data-mongodb-multi-language)

#### The entity

```java
@Document
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'language': 1, 'textProperty': 'text'}")
```

#### The repository

```java
@Query("{'language': ?0, $text: {$search: ?1, $language: ?0}}")
Stream<TheDocuemnt> findTheDocument(String language, String criteria, Sort sort);
```